# Right padding is missing from a responsive HTML table

Tags: html, css

I created a responsive HTML table to contain data of several columns. In normal computer screen, the horizontal scrollbar appears to scroll through to see hidden columns. While in mobile screen, the same goes true as well.

I applied `padding:10px;` to parent container `#tb_wrapper` but strangely padding is applied to every sides of table except RIGHT HAND SIDE. I tried to find out the issue at my best but sadly couldn't figure out it. Therefore I am posting my code and screenshots here for you guys to help me in fixing this bug.

Here you can see left, top, and bottom padding is fine.

[image]

But if we scroll through this table to rightmost then you can see my problem:

[image]

No padding for right grey border. Why is it so?

```css
 #tb_wrapper {
  border:1px solid #cccccc;
  overflow-x:auto;
  overflow-y:hidden;
  max-width:960px;
  margin:50px auto;
  padding:10px;
 }
 
 .tb_records {
  border-collapse:collapse;
  text-align:center;
  width:1200px;
 }
 
 .tb_records th {
  background-color:#5F5F5F;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  font-weight:bold;
 }
 
 .tb_records th, .tb_records td {
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid #000000;
  font-size:15px;
 }
 
 .tb_records tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color:#F2F2F2;
 }
 
 .tb_records tr:hover {
  background-color:#F5F5F5;
 }
```

```html
    <div id="tb_wrapper">
        <table class="tb_records">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Post ID</th>
                    <th>Post Name</th>
                    <th>Post URL</th>
                    <th>Post Title</th>
                    <th>Post Heading</th>
                    <th>Post Content</th>
                    <th>Post Date Published</th>
                    <th>Post Date Modified</th>
                    <th>Post Image</th>
                    <th>Post Views</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>my-post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                    <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                    <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                    <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>my-post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                    <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                    <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                    <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>my-post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                    <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                    <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                    <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>my-post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                    <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                    <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                    <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>my-post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                    <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                    <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                    <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>6</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>

                    <td>my-post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                    <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                    <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                    <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>7</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>my-post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                    <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                    <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                    <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>8</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>my-post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                    <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                    <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                    <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>9</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>my-post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                    <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                    <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                    <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>10</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>my-post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                    <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                    <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                    <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: you may use margin-right on the table to overide this default behavior.

Comment: @G-Cyr, No, please see my complete code.

Comment: Your table `.tb_records` is wider than the parent container that is why.

Comment: set the margins on the table instead padding on the parent, I did see your code ;)

Comment: @G-Cyr sorry but you are again wrong! I didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this

```css
#tb_wrapper {
  border:1px solid #cccccc;
  overflow-x:auto;
  overflow-y:hidden;
  max-width:960px;
  margin:50px auto;
  padding:10px;
 }
 
 .tb_records {
  border-collapse:collapse;
  text-align:center;
  width:1200px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: inline-table;
 }
 
 .tb_records th {
  background-color:#5F5F5F;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  font-weight:bold;
 }
 
 .tb_records th, .tb_records td {
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid #000000;
  font-size:15px;
 }
 
 .tb_records tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color:#F2F2F2;
 }
 
 .tb_records tr:hover {
  background-color:#F5F5F5;
 }
```

```html
<div id="tb_wrapper">
        <table class="tb_records">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Post ID</th>
                    <th>Post Name</th>
                    <th>Post URL</th>
                    <th>Post Title</th>
                    <th>Post Heading</th>
                    <th>Post Content</th>
                    <th>Post Date Published</th>
                    <th>Post Date Modified</th>
                    <th>Post Image</th>
                    <th>Post Views</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>my-post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                    <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                    <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                    <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>my-post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                    <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                    <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                    <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>my-post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                    <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                    <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                    <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>my-post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                    <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                    <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                    <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>my-post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                    <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                    <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                    <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>6</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>

                    <td>my-post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                    <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                    <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                    <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>7</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>my-post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                    <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                    <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                    <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>8</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>my-post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                    <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                    <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                    <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>9</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>my-post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                    <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                    <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                    <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>10</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>my-post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                    <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                    <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                    <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: add another method without using div ,  .tb_records {
  border-collapse:collapse;
  text-align:center;
  width:1200px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: inline-table;
 }

Comment: no just need display: inline-table;  i forgot remove that , hope useful for you

Answer (score 1):

Use seperate divs for `padding` and `overflow`

```css
 #tb_wrapper {
  border:1px solid #cccccc;
  max-width:960px;
  margin:50px auto;
  padding:10px;
 }
 .table-responsive{
  overflow-x:auto;
  overflow-y:hidden;
    }
 .tb_records {
  border-collapse:collapse;
  text-align:center;
  width:1200px;
 }
 
 .tb_records th {
  background-color:#5F5F5F;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  font-weight:bold;
 }
 
 .tb_records th, .tb_records td {
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid #000000;
  font-size:15px;
 }
 
 .tb_records tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color:#F2F2F2;
 }
 
 .tb_records tr:hover {
  background-color:#F5F5F5;
 }
```

```html
    <div id="tb_wrapper">
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="tb_records">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Post ID</th>
                    <th>Post Name</th>
                    <th>Post URL</th>
                    <th>Post Title</th>
                    <th>Post Heading</th>
                    <th>Post Content</th>
                    <th>Post Date Published</th>
                    <th>Post Date Modified</th>
                    <th>Post Image</th>
                    <th>Post Views</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>my-post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                    <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                    <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                    <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>my-post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                    <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                    <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                    <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>my-post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                    <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                    <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                    <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>my-post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                    <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                    <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                    <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>my-post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                    <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                    <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                    <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>6</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>

                    <td>my-post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                    <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                    <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                    <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>7</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>my-post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                    <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                    <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                    <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>8</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>my-post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                    <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                    <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                    <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>9</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>my-post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                    <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                    <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                    <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>10</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>my-post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>My Post</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                    <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                    <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                    <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It now created the same problem for bottom side. I need gap between table and its scrollbar. They are touched to each other using your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: inline-block` to `.tb_records` class and set the width to 1110px